# How to delete the more than 10 records from top table, using Sql Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete

If the number was more than 10 records, Old records clean.
that's mean,If the 15 records stored in the table, 5 first records to be erased.

Example:

```
"DELETE FROM Table WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ??? 10 ID FROM Table)"
```

Comment: that's real strange way of deleting records

Comment: You are pointing **older records**. Do you have any date records in your table? Also provide some sample data.

Comment: Do you have any column in that table that indicates the order by which the records was inserted into the table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can use `row_number()` to enumerate the values and then delete the oldest ones using `where`:

```
with todelete as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (order by id desc) as seqnum
      from t
      )
delete from todelete
    where seqnum > 10;
```

Your approach also works.  You can do:

```
delete from t
    where t.id not in (select top 10 t2.id from t t2 order by t2.id desc);
```

Note:  This uses `not in`, so it assumes that `id` is never `NULL`.  That seems reasonable in this situation.